# 'Permission denied' javascript error on modal window opening in IE8

Tags: javascript, ie

While opening any modal window (`NewForm`, `EditForm`, custom or OOTB) on a SharePoint list in Internet Explorer I get few

> SCRIPT70: Permission denied

errors. This causes problem with saving the form later (modal window is not closing).

IE is working with a standard server compatibility settings and tested solution worked before without a doubt. I've tried to deploy older packages (which I'm sure worked) on several different collections and webs and the problem persists. Error occurs only in Internet Explorer with standard settings - forcing IE9 mode and newer in Developer Tools makes it disappear.

From what I red most of that kind of problems are caused by opening modal window from different host (strict cross-origin policy), but in my case it happens even with a standard 'Add Element' modal window opened from SharePoint list directly. Error occurs with every reference to JavaScript `document` object.

Comment: Are your AAMs configured correctly? The cross-domain problems may occur if AAM are not configured well (i.e. accessing the site with a URL not correctly defined in AAM).

Comment: I have seen this same behavior recently on a site collection that used a custom master page. Is this by chance your case too?

Comment: @Evariste I'm pretty sure AAMs are correct. Besides I've tried to deploy this on several other farms with the same effect.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist This site collection uses original master page, haven't modified it. I've tried to to deploy it on a fresh farm - same problem.

Comment: I've noticed that not all forms has the same problem, but can't determine whats the cause. It happens on either built-in list forms and custom ones.

Comment: Can you tag the question with the version of SP you are using?